# Reports API - Slow Down

Tags: apex, performance, reports-api

Team,

I wrote the below class on Thursday and it was working like a dream (1 - 2 seconds to load the page).

Now, on Saturday when there have been no changes to the code since Thursday it take 15 - 20 seconds to load the page and generates a log file of > 2mb!

I know you'll say, something must have changed and I'd normally agree but this is in my private Dev instance and I'm the only one with access.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Controller

```
public class timeAllocation_handler {
Report currentReport;
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMeta;
Reports.ReportResults reportResult;

public timeAllocation_handler()
{
    currentReport = [SELECT Id FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName = 'Time_Allocation_for_Account'];
    Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Account Name'];

    Reports.ReportDescribeResult reportDescribe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(currentReport.Id);
    reportMeta = reportDescribe.getReportMetadata();

    Reports.ReportFilter[] reportFilters = new Reports.ReportFilter[]{};

    Reports.ReportFilter rf = new Reports.ReportFilter('FK_ACC_ID','equals',a.Id+'');

    rf = new Reports.ReportFilter('FK_ACC_ID','equals',a.Id);
    reportFilters.add(rf);

    //this will be set to equals in the live version
    rf = new Reports.ReportFilter('for__Timesheet2__c.for__ActivityDate__c','lessThan','LAST_MONTH');
    reportFilters.add(rf);

    rf = new Reports.ReportFilter('for__Timesheet2__c.for__ActivityDate__c','equals','THIS_YEAR');
    reportFilters.add(rf);

    reportMeta.setReportFilters(reportFilters);
}

public Reports.ReportResults getReport()
{
    if(reportResult == null)
    {
        reportResult = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(currentReport.Id, reportMeta);
    }

    return reportResult;
}

Map<String,reportItem> reportItemMap = new Map<String,ReportItem>();
Map<String,Reports.GroupingValue> downMap = new Map<String,Reports.GroupingValue>();
Map<String,Reports.GroupingValue> acrossMap = new Map<String,Reports.GroupingValue>();

public void build(Reports.Dimension rD, Reports.GroupingValue rG)
{
    //level 1
    for(Reports.GroupingValue rG1:rD.getGroupings())
    {
        setValue(rG1.getKey()+'!'+rG.getKey(),rG1);
        //level 2
        for(Reports.GroupingValue rG2:rG1.getgroupings())
        {
            setValue(rG2.getKey()+rG.getKey(),rG2);
            //level 3
            for(Reports.GroupingValue rG3:rG2.getgroupings())
            {
                setValue(rG3.getKey()+'!'+rG.getKey(),rG3);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setValue(string s,Reports.GroupingValue rG)
{
    if(reportItemMap.containsKey(s))
    {
        //reportItemMap.get(s).cellValue = rG.getLabel();
    }
}


public reportItem[] getFilteredList()
{

    cell v0 = new cell(null,null);
    cell v1 = new cell(null,null);
    cell v2 = new cell(null,null);
    cell v3 = new cell(null,null);

    return getFilteredList(v0,v1,v2,v3);
}

private reportItem[] getFilteredList(cell v0,cell v1,cell v2,cell v3)
{
    reportItem[] newList = new reportItem[]{};
    for(reportItem rItem:getReportList())
    {
        if(v0.cellKey == rItem.cellValue0.cellKey && v0.cellKey != null)
        {

        }
    }

    return newList;
}

public integer getFactSize()
{
    return getreport().getFactMap().size();
}


reportItem[] rList = new reportItem[]{};

public reportItem[] getReportList()
{
    if(rList.size() == 0)
    {
        getReport();

        for(Reports.GroupingValue rG:reportResult.getgroupingsDown().getGroupings())
        {
            reportItem xItem = new reportItem();
            xItem.xKey = rG.getKey();
            xItem.cellValue0 = new cell(rG.getLabel(),rG.getKey());

            rList.add(xItem);

            //sub totals
            yList = new reportItem[]{};
            for(reportItem yItem:getyList())
            {
                yItem.cellValue3 = yItem.cellValue1;
                yItem.cellValue2 = yItem.cellValue0;
                yItem.cellValue1 = null;
                yItem.cellValue0 = xItem.cellValue0;
                yItem.xKey = xItem.xKey;
                rList.add(yItem);
            }

            for(Reports.GroupingValue rG1:rG.getgroupings())
            {
                reportItem xItem1 = new reportItem();
                xItem1.cellValue0 = xItem.cellValue0;
                xItem1.cellValue1 = new cell(rG1.getLabel(),rG1.getKey().replace(rG.getKey()+'_',''));
                xItem1.xKey = rG1.getKey();
                rList.add(xItem1);

                yList = new reportItem[]{};
                for(reportItem yItem:getyList())
                {
                    yItem.cellValue3 = yItem.cellValue1;
                    yItem.cellValue2 = yItem.cellValue0;

                    yItem.cellValue1 = xItem1.cellValue1;
                    yItem.cellValue0 = xItem.cellValue0;

                    yItem.xKey = xItem1.xKey;

                    rList.add(yItem);
                }


                for(Reports.GroupingValue rG2:rG1.getgroupings())
                {
                    reportItem xItem2 = new reportItem();
                    xItem2.cellValue0 = xItem.cellValue0;
                    xItem2.cellValue1 = xItem1.cellValue1;
                    xItem2.cellValue2 = new cell(rG2.getLabel(),rG2.getKey());
                    xItem2.xKey = rG2.getKey();
                    rList.add(xItem2);

                    yList = new reportItem[]{};
                    for(reportItem yItem:getyList())
                    {
                        yItem.cellValue3 = yItem.cellValue1;
                        yItem.cellValue2 = yItem.cellValue0;

                        yItem.cellValue1 = xItem1.cellValue1;
                        yItem.cellValue0 = xItem.cellValue0;

                        yItem.xKey = xItem2.xKey;

                        rList.add(yItem);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        yList = new reportItem[]{};
        for(reportItem yItem:getyList())
        {
            yItem.cellValue3 = yItem.cellValue1;
            yItem.cellValue2 = yItem.cellValue0;
            yItem.cellValue1 = null;
            yItem.cellValue0 = null;
            rList.add(yItem);
        }



        reportItem xItem = new reportItem();
        xItem.cellValue0 = new cell('Grand Total','T!T');
        rList.add(xItem);

        for(reportItem rItem:rList)
        {
            if(rItem.xKey == null)
            {
                rItem.xKey = 'T';
            }

            if(rItem.yKey == null)
            {
                rItem.yKey = 'T';
            }

            //set the label
            if(getreport().getFactMap().containsKey(rItem.getKey()))
            {
                rItem.reportFact = getreport().getFactMap().get(rItem.getKey());
            }

            if(rItem.cellValue0 == null)
            {
                rItem.cellValue0 = new cell(null,'T');
            }

            if(rItem.cellValue2 == null)
            {
                rItem.cellValue2 = new cell(null,'T');
            }
        }


    }

    return rList;
}
reportItem[] yList = new reportItem[]{};
public reportItem[] getyList()
{

    if(yList.size() == 0)
    {
        Reports.GroupingValue[] rGs = reportResult.getgroupingsAcross().getGroupings();

        for(Reports.GroupingValue rG:rGs)
        {
            reportItem yItem = new reportItem();
            yItem.cellValue0 = new cell(rG.getLabel(),rG.getKey());
            yItem.yKey = rG.getKey();
            yList.add(yItem);

            Reports.GroupingValue[] rG1s = rG.getgroupings();

            for(Reports.GroupingValue rG1:rG1s)
            {
                reportItem yItem1 = new reportItem();
                yItem1.cellValue0 = yItem.cellValue0;
                yItem1.cellValue1 = new cell(rG1.getLabel(),rG1.getKey().replace(rG.getKey()+'_',''));
                yItem1.yKey = rG1.getKey();
                yList.add(yItem1);

                Reports.GroupingValue[] rG2s = rG1.getgroupings();

                for(Reports.GroupingValue rG2:rG2s)
                {   
                    reportItem yItem2 = new reportItem();
                    yItem2.cellValue0 = yItem.cellValue0;
                    yItem2.cellValue1 = yItem1.cellValue1;
                    yItem2.cellValue2 = new cell(rG2.getLabel(),rG2.getKey());
                    yItem.yKey = rG2.getKey();
                    yList.add(yItem2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return yList;
}

public class reportItem
{
    public cell cellValue0 {get;set;}
    public cell cellValue1 {get;set;}
    public cell cellValue2 {get;set;}
    public cell cellValue3 {get;set;}
    public string xKey {get;set;}
    public string yKey {get;set;}
    public Reports.ReportFact reportFact {get;set;}

    public string getKey()
    {
        return xKey + '!' + yKey;
    }
}

public class cell
{
    public string cellValue {get;set;}
    public string cellKey {get;set;}

    public cell(string v,string k)
    {
        cellValue = v;
        cellKey = k;
    }
}

public class filteredResult
{
    public reportItem[] reportItems {get;set;}
    public totalRow[] totals {get;set;}

    public filteredResult()
    {
        reportItems = new reportItem[]{};
        totals = new totalRow[]{};
    }
}

public class totalRow
{
    public string label {get;set;}
    public double value {get;set;}

    public totalRow(string l,string v)
    {
        label = l;
        value = double.valueOf(v);
    }
}

}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="timeAllocation_handler" sidebar="false" >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ReportList}" var="r" >
            <apex:column headerValue="0" value="{!r.cellValue0.cellKey}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="0" value="{!r.cellValue0.cellValue}"/>

            <apex:column headerValue="1" value="{!r.cellValue1.cellKey}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="1" value="{!r.cellValue1.cellValue}"/>

            <apex:column headerValue="2" value="{!r.cellValue2.cellKey}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="2" value="{!r.cellValue2.cellValue}"/>

            <apex:column headerValue="3" value="{!r.cellValue3.cellKey}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="3" value="{!r.cellValue3.cellValue}"/>

            <apex:column value="{!r.key}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!reportList.size}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!Factsize}"/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!r.reportFact.aggregates}" var="agg">
                <apex:column headerValue="asf" value="{!agg.label}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Any help / tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in the debug logs that indicates a slowdown in a particular part of the code?  In these situations, I tend to pop up the debug log in a text editor, go through the timestamps on the left side, and look for spots where there's a noticeable jump in time.  That has helped me get to the root of issues like this in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Just something that crossed my mind....If you have development mode on for your user settings, please try by switching it off. It sometimes is responsible to slow Pages down